# Avoid gaps in join with generated series in posgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am measuring rain amount with sensors. They have a counter which  increases whenever it rains. I'm displaying that rain amount in a chart like so:

[image]

I have a table with lots of entries and two columns (which are relevant here). The pulse is a jsonb numeric in the payload which only increases. `inserted_a`t is a datetime.

```
+--------------------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|    inserted_at     | payload  |        notes about the entry          |
+--------------------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| before timeseries  |     120  | the last entry more than 12 hours ago |
| t-10               |     120  | no rain, there is a gap before this   |
| t-9                |     122  | 2mm rain                              |
| t-8                |     122  |                                       |
| t-8                |     125  | two values, so the maximum is taken   |
| t-7                |     126  | 1mm rain                              |
| ...                |     ...  | ...                                   |
| last entry         |     135  |                                       |
+--------------------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

The desired result would be `[120, 120, 120, 120, 122, 125, 126, ..., 135]`

My current posgresql query does it like this:

```
SELECT max(t.payload) as pulse
  FROM generate_series(date_trunc('hour', now())- interval '13 hours', date_trunc('hour', now()), interval '60 min') as g(series)
  LEFT JOIN ttnmessages t
    ON t.inserted_at < g.series + interval '60 min'
    AND t.inserted_at > g.series
  WHERE t.hardware_serial like '#{hardware_serial}'
  GROUP BY g.series
  ORDER BY g.series
```

It works quite well, **but does not handle gaps in the data**. Any idea how I approach this? Ideally I'd love to receive exactly 13 results with the default result being the maximum of the previous timeframe.
The table does contain a few million entries, so execution time is important (but no issue with the current query).

**EDIT**: I explained in the first paragraph what the actual usage for this is and removed the jsonb transformation from the query.

**EDIT2**: With gaps in sensor data, the graph with the current query will look like this
[image]

Comment: I am just lost.  Why would you have 120 four times in the result set?  What 13 results do you want in the result set?  Can you explain the problem without JSONB -- handling the types just complicates the overall logic?

Comment: Does the graph image help? Right now it has not rained, so I don't have a better screenshot.

I want 13 results because I can then calculate the amount of rain within that hour. So with 13 results from the query, I can calculate 12 hours of rain.